# Providing sugar *and* object methods in a Moose role

Tags: moose

I'm working on a Moose Role that allows the consuming class to emit XML based on an 'xml_path' option specified to one or more attributes, like so:

```
package MooseX::Role::EmitsXML::Trait::HasXMLPath;

use Moose::Role;

has xml_path => (
    'is' => 'ro',
    'isa' => 'Str',
    'predicate' => 'has_xml_path',
);

has 'namespace' => (
    'is' => 'ro',
    'isa' => 'Str',
    'predicate' => 'has_namespace',
);

has 'cdata' => (
    'is' => 'ro',
    'isa' => 'Bool',
    'predicate' => 'has_cdata',
);

package MooseX::Role::EmitsXML;

our $VERSION = '0.01';

use Moose::Role;
use namespace::autoclean;
use XML::LibXML;
use Moose::Exporter;

sub has_xml {
    my ($meta, $attr_name, %opts) = @_;
    $opts{'traits'} ||= [];
    push @{$opts{'traits'}}, 'MooseX::Role::EmitsXML::Trait::HasXMLPath';
    $meta->add_attribute($attr_name, %opts);
}

Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods(
    with_meta       => [qw(has_xml)],
    also            => [qw/Moose/],
);

sub to_xml {
    my ( $self, @args ) = @_;

    my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new(); 

    for my $attr ( map { $self->meta->get_attribute($_) } $self->meta->get_attribute_list ) {
        my $reader = $attr->get_read_method;
        if ( $attr->does('XMLPath') && $attr->has_xml_path ) {
            my $val      = $self->$reader();
            my $path     = $attr->xml_path;
            my @elements = split /\//, $path;

            if ( $path =~ /^\// ) {    # Throw away blank
                shift @elements;
            }

            my $previous;
            while ( my $element = shift @elements ) {
                my $node;
                my $attrs = extract_attrs($element);
                ( my $node_name = $element ) =~ s/\[.+?\]//g;

                if ( !$previous ) {
                    if ( !$doc->documentElement ) {
                        $doc->setDocumentElement( XML::LibXML::Element->new($node_name) );
                        for my $key ( keys %{$attrs} ) {
                            $doc->documentElement->setAttribute( $key, $attrs->{$key} );
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        my $root1 = $doc->documentElement->nodeName;
                        my $root2 = $element;

                        if ( $root1 ne $root2 ) {
                            die qq{MISMATCH! Root elements do not match: "$root1" <> "$root2"};
                        }
                    }
                    $node = $doc->documentElement;
                }
                else {
                    ($node) = @{ $previous->find(qq{./$element}) };

                    if ( !$node ) {
                        $node = XML::LibXML::Element->new($node_name);
                        for my $key ( keys %{$attrs} ) {
                            $node->setAttribute( $key, $attrs->{$key} );
                        }
                        $previous->addChild($node);
                    }
                }
                $previous = $node;
            }

            # $previous has become the leaf here
            $previous->appendText($val);
        }
    }
}

sub _extract_attrs {
    my $element = shift;

    my @attr_strings = ($element =~ m/(\[.+?\])/); # Capture everything between [ and ].
    if (scalar @attr_strings > 1) {
        die q{Invalid attribute specification. Specify multiple attrs as [@attr1=val1,@attr2=val2]};
    }
    my %attrs;
    if (@attr_strings) {
        for my $string (split /,/, $attr_strings[0]) {
            my ($key, $val) = ($string =~ m/\[@?\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*"(\w+)"\s*\]/);

            if (!$key) {
                die qq{Malformed attribute specification: "$string". Should be [key="value"] (DOUBLE QUOTES MANDATORY)\n};
            }
            if (exists $attrs{$key}) {
                warn qq{Duplicate key "$key" in attrs};
            }
            $attrs{$key} = $val;
        }
    }
    return \%attrs;
}


no Moose::Role;

1;
```

However, when I try to use it:

```
package Product;

use Moose;
use MooseX::Role::EmitsXML;

# If I comment this out, has_xml works right ($meta is passed as first argument) but I don't have to_xml() available in the 
# consuming class.
# 
# If I don't, I have to_xml available in the consuming class, but has_xml doesn't work right.

with 'MooseX::Role::EmitsXML';

has_xml 'description' =>
    ( 'is' => 'ro', 'isa' => 'Str', 'xml_path' => '/Product/DescriptiveInformation/ProductDescription' );
has_xml 'item_number'    => ( 'is' => 'ro', 'isa' => 'Str',    'xml_path' => '/Product/Identifiers/ItemNumber' );
has_xml 'catalog_number' => ( 'is' => 'ro', 'isa' => 'Str',    'xml_path' => '/Product/Identifiers/CatalogNumber' );
has_xml 'upc'            => ( 'is' => 'ro', 'isa' => 'Int',    'xml_path' => '/Product/Identifiers/UPC' );
has_xml 'color'          => ( 'is' => 'ro', 'isa' => 'Str', 'xml_path' => '/Product/DescriptiveInformation/Color' );
has 'that_je_ne_sais_quoi' => ('is' => 'ro', 'isa' => 'Str' );

1;

package main;

use Test::Most;
use XML::LibXML;

my %product_args = (
    color                => 'periwinkle',
    upc                  => 1234567890123,
    item_number          => 'THX-1138',
    catalog_number       => 'KP-1652051819',
    description          => q{Oh, yes. It's very nice!},
    that_je_ne_sais_quoi => q{Something French. Or maybe Swahili.},
);
ok my $p = Product->new(%product_args), 'Created instance of class using role';

ok my $xml = $p->to_xml, 'Output XML';

ok my $doc = XML::LibXML::parse_string($xml), 'XML is valid (or at least parseable)';

for my $key (keys %product_args) {
    my $attr = $p->meta->get_attribute($key);
    if ($key ne 'that_je_ne_sais_quoi') {
        ok $attr->can('has_xml_path'), qq{Predicate 'has_xml_path' present for "$key"};
        ok my $path = $attr->xml_path, qq{Got an XML path for "$key"};
        1;
    }
}
```

As the comments say, if I comment out `with 'MooseX::Role::EmitsXML'`, then `has_xml` gets the consuming package's metaclass as the first argument, but the consuming package doesn't have `to_xml`.  If I uncomment it, the consuming package gets `to_xml`, but `has_xml` doesn't get the consuming package metaclass.  How can I get both `to_xml` and the `has_xml` sugar?

Answer (score 1):

Per ether, this is Not How It's Done.  Instead, the Role providing `with_xml` needs to be defined in a separate package, and the "ultimate" Role should apply the aforementioned to the consuming class, like so:

```
package MooseX::Role::EmitsXML::Trait::HasXMLPath;

use Moose::Role;

has xml_path => (
    'is' => 'ro',
    'isa' => 'Str',
    'predicate' => 'has_xml_path',
);

has 'namespace' => (
    'is' => 'ro',
    'isa' => 'Str',
    'predicate' => 'has_namespace',
);

has 'cdata' => (
    'is' => 'ro',
    'isa' => 'Bool',
    'predicate' => 'has_cdata',
);

package MooseX::Role::EmitsXML::ToXML;

# This package provides the to_xml() method to the consuming class

our $VERSION = '0.01';

use Moose::Role;
use namespace::autoclean;
use XML::LibXML;

sub to_xml {
    my ( $self, @args ) = @_;

    my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new(); 

    for my $attr ( map { $self->meta->get_attribute($_) } $self->meta->get_attribute_list ) {
        my $reader = $attr->get_read_method;
        if ( $attr->does('MooseX::Role::EmitsXML::Trait::HasXMLPath') && $attr->has_xml_path ) {
            my $val      = $self->$reader();
            my $path     = $attr->xml_path;
            my @elements = split /\//, $path;

            if ( $path =~ /^\// ) {    # Throw away blank
                shift @elements;
            }

            my $previous;
            while ( my $element = shift @elements ) {
                my $node;
                my $attrs = extract_attrs($element);
                ( my $node_name = $element ) =~ s/\[.+?\]//g;

                if ( !$previous ) {
                    if ( !$doc->documentElement ) {
                        $doc->setDocumentElement( XML::LibXML::Element->new($node_name) );
                        for my $key ( keys %{$attrs} ) {
                            $doc->documentElement->setAttribute( $key, $attrs->{$key} );
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        my $root1 = $doc->documentElement->nodeName;
                        my $root2 = $element;

                        if ( $root1 ne $root2 ) {
                            die qq{MISMATCH! Root elements do not match: "$root1" <> "$root2"};
                        }
                    }
                    $node = $doc->documentElement;
                }
                else {
                    ($node) = @{ $previous->find(qq{./$element}) };

                    if ( !$node ) {
                        $node = XML::LibXML::Element->new($node_name);
                        for my $key ( keys %{$attrs} ) {
                            $node->setAttribute( $key, $attrs->{$key} );
                        }
                        $previous->addChild($node);
                    }
                }
                $previous = $node;
            }

            # $previous has become the leaf here
            $previous->appendText($val);
        }
    }

    return "$doc";
}

sub _extract_attrs {
    my $element = shift;

    my @attr_strings = ($element =~ m/(\[.+?\])/); # Capture everything between [ and ].
    if (scalar @attr_strings > 1) {
        die q{Invalid attribute specification. Specify multiple attrs as [@attr1=val1,@attr2=val2]};
    }
    my %attrs;
    if (@attr_strings) {
        for my $string (split /,/, $attr_strings[0]) {
            my ($key, $val) = ($string =~ m/\[@?\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*"(\w+)"\s*\]/);

            if (!$key) {
                die qq{Malformed attribute specification: "$string". Should be [key="value"] (DOUBLE QUOTES MANDATORY)\n};
            }
            if (exists $attrs{$key}) {
                warn qq{Duplicate key "$key" in attrs};
            }
            $attrs{$key} = $val;
        }
    }
    return \%attrs;
}
no Moose::Role;

1;

package MooseX::Role::EmitsXML;

# This package applies the role providing to_xml to the consuming class,
# and creates the 'has_xml' sugar

use Moose::Exporter;

sub has_xml {
    my ($meta, $attr_name, %opts) = @_;
    $opts{'traits'} ||= [];
    push @{$opts{'traits'}}, 'MooseX::Role::EmitsXML::Trait::HasXMLPath';
    $meta->add_attribute($attr_name, %opts);
}

Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods(
    with_meta       => [qw(has_xml)],
    base_class_roles => [qw(MooseX::Role::EmitsXML::ToXML)],
);
```